# Session Id Length in Tomcat

Tags: session, tomcat

We need to change the session ID length generated by tomcat. By default it is 32 bytes, unfortunately we need a session ID length of 20. Looking online I can see the `StandardManager` seems to manage this which extends `PersistanceManager`.

Does anyone know if the `sessionIdLength` can be modified in the tomcat config? If so what files?

An alternative would be to create a custom `Manager` which simply overrides/sets the `sessionidLength`. Is this possible? How do you tell tomcat to use the custom manager in the config?

Comment: It's 32 characters and not 32 bytes. The config parameter expects number of bytes. The default is 16 bytes = 32 chars.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the StandardManager via config file.  The [Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html) element can be nested inside any Context.

So, modify whichever config file has your Context.  It might be the server.xml located in the conf directory.  Or a context.xml located in the META-INF directory of your war file.

To provide a default for the entire server, edit your $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml. Uncomment the Manager line, and add the sessionIdLength attribute.

```
<Manager sessionIdLength="10" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,

I added the above line to my /conf/context.xml with no effect. I am not sure if this is an issue but I also have <Resource> and <Realm> tags in the contect.xml.

Comment: I had to delete my JSESSIONID cookie, then restart Tomcat to get a shorter cookie.  Tomcat by default will persist Session information to disk during a restart.  So I think it was persisting the longer cookie, and loading it back on startup.  So, try to delete you JSESSIONID cookie, restart Tomcat.  Hopefully that will result in the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `sessionIdLength` attribute to the  element of your Tomcat's `context.xml` (or wherever you're manager is defined).

Incidentally, [the docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html) say that the default is 16, not 32.

Comment: The docs say 16 bytes.  The cookie is encoded as hex, so 32=16

Answer (score 1):

FYI - sessionIdLength as a property of Manager is deprecated in Tomcat releases > 7.x. To alter the default JSESSIONID length of 16 (32 hex encoded characters) you must alter the sessionIdLength of the SessionIdGenerator.  This is one of many public links on the topic: http://openpage-auth.jblearning.com/docs/config/sessionidgenerator.html

Example:

```
<Manager pathname="">
   <!-- this will produce a 40 hex encoded character JSESSIONID -->
   <SessionIdGenerator sessionIdLength="20"/>
</Manager>
```