# Is it possible to change the length of JSESSIONID session cookie value?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty

The actual JSESSIONID value is a 16 chars string and I would like it to be a 32 chars string.

I've seen that this is possible to **change the length of the sessionid cookie value** on Tomcat servers ( [Session Id Length in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132581/session-id-length-in-tomcat) ) but I can't find a way to do so for my Google App Engine app running Jetty.

The only session cookie configuration available seems to be on its name ( https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/SessionIds )

Anyone succeded in changing the sessionid's length on app-engine ?

Comment: no, you can't do that. btw, why you want to do this?

Comment: Yes write a custom [SessionIdManager](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/AbstractSessionIdManager.html).

Comment: @StefanLindenberg you cannot do that on gae

Comment: A didn't notice that tag.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I felt like a 32 chars string would have been stronger against some case of session hijacking...

Comment: @MaximeT that's probably reasonable in some cases. but unfortunately gae doesn't provide such ways to customize internal jetty

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a custom [SessionIdManager](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.12.v20160915/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/SessionIdManager.html) isn't possible on the [standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) due to the sandbox. However, this should still be possible on the [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) as there are no runtime class restrictions.