# how to change the session id length in spring boot

Tags: session, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I am using spring boot for a webapp running on embedded tomcat. I want to change the session id length from the default 16 bytes to 32 bytes.

I had a look into this post
[Session Id Length in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132581/session-id-length-in-tomcat)

and learnt that we can provide the following in the tomcat config file context.xml

How do we do the equivalent in spring boot?
I mean how do we do that programatically?

Comment: Have a look at the docs, they tell you when to use application.properties and how to change values that are not exposed directly: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html

Comment: Besides that: is there any reason why you use Tomcat 7 ? I think Tomcat 8 is the standard in Spring Boot (at least when you use a current version)

Comment: yeah It is Tomcat 8. edited the tag.

Answer (score 4):

This did the trick:

```java
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig implements TomcatContextCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(Context context) {
        context.getManager().getSessionIdGenerator().setSessionIdLength(32);
    }
}
```